# chrome not showing favicon on subpages

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

I cannot for the life of me figure this one out.

I have my favicon showing on the frontpage of: http://www.pokerwomennews.com/
But on specific post pages, the favicon is not showing in chrome. The html for the favicons are exactly the same, and valid. Can anyone tell me what is being parsed incorrectly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the string `"UA-54046177-1"` is being output between the `head` tags. If you view the page source, you will find it in this section.

```
<!-- Google Webmaster Tools plugin for WordPress -->
UA-54046177-1
<script>
```

This is causing Chrome to error-handle the invalid HTML, and assume that is where the `body` starts, and pushing the favicon link elements below it into the `body`. You can see the effect of this in Chrome's Elements panel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because chrome first checks for a favicon.ico file, in the root of your web site, and it's finding one. The problem is that it's a zero-length, empty file. So google is showing what it thinks you want - nothing.

Remove the empty favicon.ico file entirely, and it will fix your issue.